# Why isn't my detector rail igniting my TNT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to blow my friend up on our server to get back at him :) The problem is, it doesn't work for some reason. My TNT is connected to a detector track, but it isn't activated by minecart going over that detector.
[Here's a video of my setup](http://lubimvlky.kvalitne.cz/y-u-no-xplode.avi). In the video, I put the minecart on the detector. I then  show you the circuit and how it doesn't ignite the TNT. I found that when the minecart stays on the trigger, it actually activates 2nd batch of TNT, which was quite a surprise, since I tested it by riding the minecart and it didn't trigger anything.

So the question is: Where is the problem on the non-exploded side of the trap? and why doesn't minecart trigger the trap at all when it just runs over the detector track?

Comment: By "trigger railroad" are you referring to a detector rail?

Comment: More importantly, why does your video have a Russian? speech as the soundtrack?

Comment: More importantly, YouTube?

Comment: @thedaian By the tld I'm gonna guess czech.

Comment: Oh crap I haven't removed the audio.. I was watching the parlament discussion about how our govrnment in Slovakia is going to fall today because of Greece debt :) Yeah I ment detector rail /englishfail

Comment: Keep in mind that TNT takes a minute to detonate, so you might have to run it a while to get it all to blow, or detonate a line of TNT at once.

Comment: For some reason this question makes me think of Wyle E Cyote asking for help before returning to the lit TNT...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redstone wire is a little tricky with how it can and can't turn.  Replacing the sandstone under your TNT with more TNT and running the wire straight up to that should detonate it.

Alternately, elevate your wire to the level of your TNT before it reaches it, and have the wire run straight into your lowest TNT block.